# My code have an error and I don't know why

Tags: excel, vba, solution, vsm

Hi I have the next code in VBA:

```
Sub EscribirPregunta()
    Dim preguntas As Range
    Dim pregunta As Range
    Dim boton As Button
    Dim preguntaSeleccionada As String
    Dim celdasLista As Range
    Dim celda As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    ' Establecer el rango de las preguntas
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set preguntas = ws.Range("C2:C23")
    
    ' Verificar si todas las celdas en B2:B23 contienen "1"
    Dim celdasB As Range
    Set celdasB = ws.Range("B2:B23")
    
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(celdasB, 1) = celdasB.Count Then
        
        ' Borrar los "1" de la columna B
        celdasB.Value = ""
        
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Obtener el botón que activó la macro
    Set boton = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    
    ' Verificar si ya hay una pregunta en la celda destino
    If boton.TopLeftCell.Value <> "" Then
        Exit Sub ' Salir de la macro si ya hay una pregunta en la celda destino
    End If
    
    ' Crear un rango de las celdas de la lista (L2:L16) sin incluir la celda actual
    Set celdasLista = ws.Range("L2:L16")
    
    ' Filtrar las preguntas que no tienen un "1" en la columna B
    Dim preguntasFiltradas As String
    Dim preguntaRow As Integer
    
    preguntasFiltradas = ""
    preguntaRow = 0
    
    For i = 1 To preguntas.Count
        ' Seleccionar una pregunta aleatoria sin repetición de las preguntas filtradas
        Set pregunta = preguntas.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, preguntas.Count))
        
        'Comprobar que esa pregunta se haya utizado o no (visualizando si la columna B tiene 1)
        If ws.Cells(pregunta.Row, "B") <> 1 Then 'Si no se ha utilizado aun
            preguntaSeleccionada = pregunta.Value
            preguntaRow = pregunta.Row
            Exit For
        Else 'Si se ha utilizado
            preguntaSeleccionada = ""
            preguntaRow = 0
        End If
        
    Next
    
    ' Mostrar la pregunta seleccionada en la celda del botón
    ws.Cells(boton.TopLeftCell.Row, "L").Value = preguntaSeleccionada
    
    ' Obtener la celda correspondiente en la columna B
    Set celdaB = ws.Cells(preguntaRow, "B")
    
    ' Escribir "1" en la celda correspondiente en la columna B
    celdaB.Value = 1
End Sub
```

And in `Set celdaB = ws.Cells(preguntaRow, "B")` sometimes it give me error 1004. Why?

I try everything I know and I expected the reason why it work sometimes and sometimes no.

Comment: Step through your code, line by line, by pressing F8, and see what value has been assigned to preguntaRow when the error occurs.  It's likely that it has been assigned the value 0.

Comment: An error 1004 will occur if the variable preguntaRow still has a value of 0 after exiting the For...Next loop.

Comment: It looks like when you wrote the code, you assumed the first row's index was 0, and it's not.

Comment: `For i = 1 To preguntas.Count` - there is no guarantee that you'll hit on an unused question within this many iterations - you should probably just use a `Do` loop and let it run until you get an unused one, or until there are no unused questions left in the list....

Comment: Tim you are a mastermind

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it:

```vb
Function EscribirPregunta()
    
    Dim celdasB As Range, rando As Long, f, ws As Worksheet, boton As Button
    Dim tlc As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Set tlc = ws.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
    If Len(tlc.Value) > 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Set celdasB = ws.Range("B2:B23") 'range with "used" flag
    
    rando = Application.RandBetween(1, celdasB.Cells.Count)
    
    'find the first empty cell after cell # `rando`
    '   (Find always loops around after the last cell)
    Set f = celdasB.Find("", after:=celdasB.Cells(rando), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        'use the question from Col C
        tlc.EntireRow.Columns("L").Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
        f.Value = 1                       'flag as used
    Else
        celdasB.ClearContents             'all questions are used: reset
    End If
    
End Function
```